# Populate data in an unlinked PowerPoint Chart

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm looking to populate charts in a presentation. I normally create "Shell decks" for my presentations where I strip out the data from a previous presentation (by hand) and then I go into an excel file look up what values I need to paste in and then paste it populate the graph. I do this for every graph manually. This all seems very easily done in VBA, I have every part of the code up until editing the data in the chart. I can't figure it out.

This is my best attempt at setting the first bar in a chart = 7.5, and it's laughable:

`Shapes.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values(1) = 7.5`

Could I please get some help figuring out what I would need to do for this?

P.S. I can't create a chart in excel and then paste into PowerPoint, I must edit the one already there.

Thanks!

Comment: how many bars are there in the chart?

Comment: Every chart will have a different amount depending on the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the worksheet object that feeds data to a chart in powerpoint

```
 Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.activesheet
```

so you should be able to copy a range from excel into powerpoint

Comment: Hey again @jsotola ! Thank you for the response! I tried working with this but for some reason I wasn't able to change the values this way. The only way I was able to make it work is by opening the ChartData and editing the excel file behind the chart like this: `With shpe.Chart.ChartData
                             .Activate
                                .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B12:B15").Value = 7.5
                                .Workbook.Close
                            End With` Do you know if the method you proposed can do it without having to open the excel file in the back?

Comment: leave out the `.activate` and the `.Workbook.Close`

Comment: That is neat! But I meant something like `Shapes.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Point(1) = 7.5` or like the one I have in my original question?

Comment: When you edit it by hand you have to do what you said and then edit the excel sheet to update values... What I am thinking is sort of the reverse. I'm thinking VBA can just tell the graph what numbers it wants for each bar (Since we can find what values the chart has without having to open "edit data" and we can select each individual bar and change their properties, then why not also change the values without opening "edit data"?). So in essence it would be instead of Excel telling PowerPoint what to do with the graph, I want PowerPoint to tell Excel what to do with it's Sheet.

Comment: doing the "edit data" either manually or through VBA is the only way that i can see. how many bars are you talking about? ..... maybe you could use a form with sliders to manipulate the values.

Comment: In the end (after many many posts to stackoverflow lol) I hope to be able to run through all graphs that will be marked through their title, and find the correct data from a workbook I have and update the chart, by adjusting chart data size and making sure everything that is pasted in has the right corresponding colors etc... I'm not sure how a form with sliders would work for this? I'm not really sure I know what a slider is aside from a pivottable slider. @jsotola

Comment: my bad ... spinner control or a scroll bar control .... something that moves up and down in the userForm

Comment: Hey, so I tried removing the `.Activate` part of my code and it doesn't work to update the graph. Do you know of any other tricks to make it work? Current code: `With c.ChartData
Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Clear
ShWork.UsedRange.Copy ' all the data added to ShWork
Worksheets(1).Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With`

Comment: If this is an Excel embedded object, it will be different to access then a chart created in PowerPoint.  Also, what version of PPT you are using will change the way you access the object.   If you are having to activate the chart object, it is most likely an embedded excel object.

Comment: @mooseman I believe it's a PowerPoint chart. There is no sheet that is linked to any of the graphs, at least not one I can open other than when I click "edit chart".

Comment: Everywhere I looked, Point.Value does not exist

Comment: Points: A collection of all the Point objects in the specified series in a chart.
You are going to have to edit the chartdata to change the value of a point on a line. 
Try something like this:
Shape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = 70.5